# Two mandatory entries are blocking each other

Tags: cognito-forms

I am looking how to ask multiple questions where the user only should choose 1 "Most important"and 1 "Least important".

So suppose I have stated 4 questions the form should only allow for 2 entries: 1 Least and 1 Most and not allow more entries / change the 1 entry over to the other.

Is that possible with Cognito? If so, how?

Comment: Hi! Please submit a support ticket (https://www.cognitoforms.com/supportrequest/), and our support team can take a closer look at your form and the scenario you're trying to achieve.